# How to remove redundant matches between two strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, match

Given two strings str1 and str2 I have a list of matches describing shared substrings as intervals in the form of [str1_beg, str1_end, str2_beg, str2_end]. I want to remove redundant matches where str1_beg, str1_end and str2_beg, str2_end from a match are embedded in some other match.

Comment: If I need to loop though all matches and for each match loop though all matches to determine if a match is embedded it is going to be slow. How about sorting first?

Answer (score 0):

For each [beg_index, end_index] find [beg_index_new, end_index_new] and remove the ones that satisfy end_index < end_index_new and beg_index >= beg_index_new.

And that's O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you can store your matches more efficiently.

```
[str_beg,str2_beg,match_len]
```

This will also make it very easy to check for redundancy, for example

```
for match in matches:
  for i in xrange(len(matches)):
    if matches[i][:2] == match[:2] and mathches[i][2] < match[2]:
      del matches[i]
```

I'm assuming your list of matches is assigned to a variable called matches, and has the structure I proposed above, so the ma. I'm using the < operator and not the <= operator, because in the case they are equal, they're the exact same match, and I'm assuming you won't have the same match twice.
Where I'm checking both matche's [:2] slice, I'm chec king the first 2 elements of their lists, which are the starting positions.